# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, manifest, crash

I've tried all possible solutions to this problem, but nothing seems to work... The problem occured, when i've updated my SDK Tools version from r16 to r19 and SDK Platform-tools to r11. I have all classes included to the manifest, and everything worked before this update. do you have an idea how to fix this problem? (i tried a lot of solutions from this site and others...)

Here is my Error log:

```
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.bugfullabs.depress/com.bugfullabs.depress.Splash}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bugfullabs.depress.Splash
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bugfullabs.depress.Splash
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1039)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
05-17 23:29:10.888: E/AndroidRuntime(20945):    ... 11 more
```

Here is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bugfullabs.depress"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DEpressActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Credits"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".game.LevelSelect"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".game.GameActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".game.FinishScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is your `Splash` class `public` and non-`abstract`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can't find the class: `com.bugfullabs.depress.Splash.` First thing is to make sure there's not a typo in the package name. (seems like it should be bugfullaps)

Next, is the Splash class contained in a library? If so, check your Java Build Path configuration and make sure under the Order and Export tab that your library file is checked so that it's exported with the application.

EDIT: Just remembered, if you have a `lib` directory, rename it to `libs.` That's one of the things that changed from the version you were using. Good luck!

Comment: dude, you're great! all i had to do was to rename this freakin' lib folder... i almost lost my mind... :D thanks a lot!! could you tell me, where did you find documentation about those changes? i haven't came across it when i was looking for some help on d.android.com THANKS A LOT!!!!

Comment: Awesome, glad you can get back to actual coding! I had the exact same problem (and a few others) when I updated the eclipse plugin. The answer was in the logs. There was two exceptions, one at the end that didn't help, and the useful one was a few pages up! That was actually a valuable lesson, lol.

Comment: Haha, nice! i haven't tried reading logs yet, first i tried here :D thanks a lot again, next time, i'll check logs....... i'd vote your answer up, but i haven't got 15 reputation points yet... (if i'll get, i'll vote you up!) stackoverflow is really great i have to say... such valuable solution came so fast1

Comment: very nice! it's necessary to rename libs back to lib in r19. People read log properly before asking)