# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ... bad method handle type 7

Tags: android, exception

I recently installed another ROM on my Android Device (Mi Mix 2 - now 8.0 was 9.0) which is an older Android Version than the other one was. To make my project work I had to change the minSdkVersion to 26 (was 27). I tried to run the app on my phone but I am getting an exception which I do not quite understand. I didn´t change anything besides the minSdkVersion.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tobia.core, PID: 2776
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tobia.core/com.example.tobia.core.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.tobia.core.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(Unknown Source:454)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(Unknown Source:30)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Unknown Source:80)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:21)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Unknown Source:68)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Unknown Source:11)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Unknown Source:200)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.tobia.core.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(Unknown Source:116)
        ... 9 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
            ... 12 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 15 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk': Bad method handle type 7
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(Unknown Source:47)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(Unknown Source:8)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(Unknown Source:230)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(Unknown Source:26)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(Unknown Source:24)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(Unknown Source:698)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Unknown Source:502)
                ... 6 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(Unknown Source:47)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(Unknown Source:8)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(Unknown Source:230)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(Unknown Source:26)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(Unknown Source:24)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(Unknown Source:698)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Unknown Source:502)
                ... 6 more
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk': Bad method handle type 7]
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.tobia.core-lr4S82vYgys_Rc2X2Bt6vw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk]
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643970/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity)

Comment: It can't find this class "com.example.tobia.core.LoginActivity"

Comment: Yes, but what can I do about it? If I start the app on a friends phone (Android 9), it will work just as usual.